# strange files in project

Tags: javascript, image, apache, virus

I have problem with my page, is it normal that the files which normally should be image extension are txt?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IHTU.png)

My javascript files are blocked, and this issue is simultaneous.
I`ve searched eventual virus but nothing was found.

Comment: Sounds to me like your server isn't applying the correct mime type to different file types.

Comment: But why the others are fine. I use only jpg,png and svg.

Comment: The path to the files may also be wrong and you're generating a 404 page. `images/` doesn't look like a file, it looks like a folder

Comment: Ok, it was me in css, the problems with this page are from otherside. Thank you!